# How to implement dynamic button styling using tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

### What I Want:

I have a `Button` component, which accepts a `variant` prop. I want the `className` for the button to change based on the prop passed to it.

The goal is to avoid using `if/else` statements buttons, instead using a single button that dynamically changes based on the need.

### Things to Note:

- I'm using Tailwindcss as the primary styling engine.

### Ideal Solution:

```js
// provide the variant to component:
<Button variant="default" />

// would return:
<button className={variantClasses.default} />
```

### Button Component:

```js
interface Props {
  variant: string;
  innerText: string;
}

function Button({ variant, innerText }: Props) {
  // classes for all variants
  const variantClasses = {
    error: "...classes",
    default: "...classes",
  };

  // if no variant provided, return an error variant.
  if (!variant) {
    return <button className={variantClasses.error}>Error</button>;
  }
  // else return the correct variant with matching styles.
  else {
    return (
      <button className={`${variantClasses}.${variant}`}>
        {innerText || "Button"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

### What I've Tried:

- Changing the interpolation values inside button `className`.
- Using an array for `variantClasses` instead of an object.

Comment: I don't know what `tailwindcss` is, but for this kind of situations a just create a state variable with the default `classname` defined in `css`, let's call it `myStyle` and set the class of the component as `className={this.state.myClass}`, then whenever you want you can change that `myClass` using `this.setState({myClass: 'another_class')` to change to another class also defined in `css`.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

Tailwind does not support interpolation through classes the same way other css solutions do, so a workaround was needed. We can do this instead:

**Here's what to do**

1. Define array of variants, providing `name` and `className` attributes.
2. Search the array for an entry where `name` matches `variant` provided.
3. If nothing matches, throw error... else create a new variable containing matching classes.
4. Provide new variable to `className` prop on button component.

```js
interface Props {
  variant: string;
  innerText: string;
}

function Button({ variant, innerText }: Props) {
  const variantClasses = [
    {
      name: "error",
      className:
        "...classes",
    },
    {
      name: "filled",
      className:
        "...classes",
    },
  ];
  let activeClass = variantClasses.find((v) => v.name === variant);

  // if matching variant is not found, throw error variant
  if (!activeClass) {
    return <button className={variantClasses[0].className}>Error</button>;
  }
  // if variant found, return matching class
  else {
    return (
      <button className={activeClass?.className}>
        {innerText || "Button"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```